# Path planning on a prerecorded global path

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone.
I m working on an AGV for material handling in warehouses. I want to develop a planning algorithm that will use a prerecorded path and will calculate the shortest path to and from various stations in that path. To do that, I will record the amcl_poses in a yaml file and publish those coordinates on nav_msgs/path msg. Whenever a goal will be given, this planner will be called and calculate the path between the current pose and the goal pose. then the move_base will use that path to generate local_path and velocities.
But I don't know how to achieve this. Please suggest ways to develop this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/414859/path-planning-on-a-prerecorded-global-path/) by [Saurabh Rahatekar](https://answers.ros.org/users/56348/saurabh-rahatekar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2023-04-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming that I got your question correct.

You can record the poses at a low frequency (or down-sample later) and create an adjacency matrix for the entire sequence - adjacent poses will be connected and others won't be. Post that you can run any graph search algorithm across any two given poses and come up with a global plan. Then you can feed this plan to the move_base.

---

Originally posted by [Gaurav Gupta](https://answers.ros.org/users/72874/gaurav-gupta/) with karma: 276 on 2023-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Saurabh Rahatekar](https://answers.ros.org/users/56348/saurabh-rahatekar/) on 2023-05-02**:
Thank you so much for responding. I came across the move_base_flex. I am trying to use the exec_path. As you suggested, I will use the search algorithm and feed it to exec_path.